# Which Stack Exchange website for printer problems?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a problem with my printer and my Mac and Adobe illustrator. Which Stack Exchange website would I use for this? Is there a Stack Exchange website I would use for this?

Adobe Illustrator's colors change when they are printed with my HP printer but not with any other printer or any other program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No guarantees, but in this specific case, you could try on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com. I know there are people there with very thorough professional printing experience.

Other than that, generally,  I think this falls inside [Super User's](http://superuser.com) scope as well.

Wherever you post,  make sure you add as much detail as possible - what kind of image you are trying to print, what the colour differences look like, what printer driver you are using...

Comment: graphicsdesign.stackexchange is probably not the place since they are voting to close my question here https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/162400/epson-printer-prints-weird-yellow-magenta-cyan-ending

Answer (score 8):

[Super User](https://superuser.com/) would be appropriate for your question as is reflected by https://superuser.com/help/on-topic